# How can I read a file encoded in utf-16 in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

my Problem is that I parse a CSV file but all special characters (ä,ö,ü) are shown by �. I have search here but it doesn't solve my problem. I have read something about:

```
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('import.csv','utf16le')
or:

var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('import.csv','ucs2')
```

but this doesn't work..

Here my code to parse the CSV file:

```
const parse = require("csv-parse/lib/sync");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
var mysql = require('mysql');
//var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '--------',
    user: '--------',
    password: '---------',
    database: '---------'
});


module.exports = req => {

    const filePath = req.file.path;


    const csvContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

    var records = parse(csvContent, {
        skip_empty_lines: true,
        skip_lines_with_error: true,
        delimiter: ";"

    });


    function getFieldNameArray(row) {
        return row.reduce((fieldNames, originalFieldName) => {
            let fieldName = originalFieldName;
            let uniqifier = 1;
            while (fieldNames.includes(fieldName)) {
                fieldName = `${originalFieldName}${++uniqifier}`;  
            }
            fieldNames.push(fieldName);
            return fieldNames;
        }, []);
    }

    const fieldNames = getFieldNameArray(records[0]);

    records = records.slice(1).map((currentRow, index) => {
        return currentRow.reduce((prev, value, index) => {
            prev[fieldNames[index]] = value;
            return prev;
        }, {});
    }, records)


    console.log(records);
```

Comment: How do you know they're utf-16 encoded? Actually, the fact that all the other characters display fine suggests that it might be binary encoded instead of utf-16, like you think... in which case `binary` or `latin1` should work.

Comment: How can i implement this?

Comment: Same way as your previous attempt, but either with the string `binary` or `latin1` for the encoding parameter... (they're equivalent)

Comment: it works :) thanks